# Android TabHost- Opening a new TabLayout from a button click

Tags: android, button, tabs, onclick, android-tabhost

I have created my TabLayout, and it works fine when I have set up to be the first screen to load from my main class. I followed the tutorial here: http://joshclemm.com/blog/?p=136

However, I don't want it to be first thing to load.

I have an application with a `splashscreen`, then go to a `home` screen with no tabs. It has a bunch of buttons on it. When you then click one of the buttons I want to load that view which is placed in a `tabgroup` and then you have regular tabs to click around.
Any ideas how to do this basic thing on Android?

I keep getting a Runtime exception error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ttj.android.ft/ttj.android.ft.Transfers}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'
```

Here is my `onCreate` method code.

I have a button called `Transfers`, when it is clicked the `Transfers.class activity`, which is a tablayout should open but doesn't. The activity is in the android manifest. I'm a noob, so I know I'm probably doing something very simple wrong here.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button Records, Transfers, Leagues;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    Transfers = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bTransfers);



    Transfers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent openTransfers = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    Transfers.class);
            startActivity(openTransfers);

        }
    });
```

Here is my Android Manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ttj.android.ft.STARTINGPOINT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".Transfers"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ttj.android.ft.TRANSFERS" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here is the log from logcat when it crashes.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?
at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:680)
at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:346)
at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:236)
at ttj.android.ft.Transfers.onCreate(Transfers.java:52)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
```

Transfer Activity code

```
public class Transfers extends TabActivity {



    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.m_transfers);

    TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();        


    Intent intentTeams = new Intent().setClass(this, TransfersTeams.class);
    TabSpec teamsTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("TEAMS").setIndicator("")
            .setContent(intentTeams);

    Intent intentSummary = new Intent().setClass(this,
            TransfersSummary.class);
    TabSpec summaryTab = mTabHost.newTabSpec("SUMMARY").setIndicator("")
            .setContent(intentSummary);


    mTabHost.addTab(teamsTab);
    mTabHost.addTab(summaryTab);

            mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);


}
```

**FIXED**

My classes TransfersTeams and TransfersSummary were extending TabActivity. I changed this to Activity and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

In the MainActivity try to replace

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="ttj.android.ft.STARTINGPOINT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

With

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have shared the manifest fully. I already have a MAIN intent for the splash page. I edited my post to include the full manifest.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `Transfers` activity, not in `MainActivity`. And as the error clearly tells you, you are forgetting to call `setup()` for your `TabHost`.

Comment: Hi. I have added the Transfers activity code to my question and you can that  I am calling setup();

Comment: @tiptopjat: Have you? I don't see it

Answer (score 0):

If you start tab item activity separately, it will not have the tab bar on the top. To do this, you shuold start you tab host activity, and setCurrentTab to which tab you want to appear.

Comment: Should I just add tabHost.setCurrentTab(0) at the end of my Transfer class?

Comment: Yes, that it. I see you have 2 tabs here.

Comment: I've added setCurrentTab. Still no joy. Please see modified code in original question.

Comment: did you change your current tab? I see ` mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);` If you want appear another tab, just chang it to 1;

Comment: I have changed it to setCurrentTab(1); but it still doesn't work. I now get a longer error log file from logcat. Please see revised answer.